# Remove duplicate results from Oracle query

Tags: oracle, plsql, duplicates, union, plsqldeveloper

Thank you in advance for the help.
This is the query that gives an extra result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT npi.id_provider AS npi_provider,
  mcnpi.num_contract_max                   AS num_contract_max,
  mcd.id_provider                          AS mcd_provider,
  provservloc.dte_effective                AS dte_effective,
  provservloc.dte_end                      AS dte_end,
--Case modified to pull condition from t_pmp_svc_loc for when dte_end > today
CASE
    WHEN provservloc.dte_end > 20180611 THEN 
        CASE WHEN mcfte.dte_end > 20180611 THEN mcfte.num_hrs_week ELSE 0 END
    ELSE 0 END                          AS num_hrs_week,
--Case added to handle Num_Current_Panel results
CASE
    WHEN provservloc.dte_end > 20180611 THEN
        CASE WHEN mcfte.dte_end > 20180611 THEN pmppanelrestrict.num_current_panel ELSE 0 END
    ELSE 0 END                       AS num_current_panel,
--Case added to handle Num_Future_Panel
CASE
    WHEN provservloc.dte_end > 20180611 THEN
        CASE WHEN mcfte.dte_end > 20180611 THEN pmppanelrestrict.num_future_panel ELSE 0 END
    ELSE 0 END                       AS num_future_panel,
--Case added to handle Num_Max_Panel numbers
CASE
    WHEN provservloc.dte_end > 20180611 THEN
        CASE WHEN mcfte.dte_end > 20180611 THEN pmppanelrestrict.num_max_panel ELSE 0 END
    ELSE 0 END                       AS num_max_panel,
  pmppanelrestrict.ind_panel_hold    AS ind_panel_hold,
  mcnpi.sak_npi              AS sak_npi ,
  provservloc.sak_prov,
  provservloc.sak_prov_loc
FROM t_pmp_svc_loc provservloc
  LEFT JOIN T_PR_IDENTIFIER MCD ON PROVSERVLOC.SAK_PROV_LOC = MCD.SAK_PROV_LOC AND PROVSERVLOC.SAK_PROV = MCD.SAK_PROV
  INNER JOIN t_pr_identifier npi on npi.sak_prov_loc = mcd.sak_prov_loc AND npi.sak_prov = mcd.sak_prov
  LEFT JOIN t_mc_fte mcfte ON provservloc.sak_prov = mcfte.sak_prov AND provservloc.sak_prov_loc = mcfte.sak_prov_loc
  LEFT JOIN t_mc_pmp_panel_restrict pmppanelrestrict ON provservloc.sak_pmp_ser_loc = pmppanelrestrict.sak_pmp_ser_loc
  LEFT JOIN t_mc_npi mcnpi ON mcnpi.sak_npi = mcd.sak_npi
  LEFT JOIN t_pr_php_elig elig ON provservloc.sak_prov_loc = elig.sak_prov_loc
WHERE 
PROVSERVLOC.SAK_PUB_HLTH       = 23
AND elig.sak_prov_pgm          = 57
AND elig.cde_enroll_status     IN ( 'A' ,'G', 'X' )
AND mcfte.cde_status1          != 'H'
AND mcd.cde_prov_id_type        = 'MCD'
AND NPI.CDE_PROV_ID_TYPE        = 'NPI'
AND npi.id_provider                = '123456789'

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT npi.id_provider AS npi_provider,
  mcnpi.num_contract_max                   AS num_contract_max,
  mcd.id_provider                          AS mcd_provider,
  provservloc.dte_effective                AS dte_effective,
  provservloc.dte_end                      AS dte_end,
NULL AS NUM_HRS_WEEK,
NULL AS num_current_panel,
NULL AS NUM_FUTURE_PANEL,
NULL AS num_max_panel,
NULL  AS ind_panel_hold,
  mcnpi.sak_npi              AS sak_npi ,
  provservloc.sak_prov,
  provservloc.sak_prov_loc
FROM t_pmp_svc_loc provservloc
  LEFT JOIN T_PR_IDENTIFIER MCD ON PROVSERVLOC.SAK_PROV_LOC = MCD.SAK_PROV_LOC AND PROVSERVLOC.SAK_PROV = MCD.SAK_PROV
  INNER JOIN T_PR_IDENTIFIER NPI ON NPI.SAK_PROV_LOC = MCD.SAK_PROV_LOC AND NPI.SAK_PROV = MCD.SAK_PROV
  LEFT JOIN t_mc_npi mcnpi ON mcnpi.sak_npi = mcd.sak_npi
  LEFT JOIN T_PR_PHP_ELIG ELIG ON PROVSERVLOC.SAK_PROV_LOC = ELIG.SAK_PROV_LOC
WHERE PROVSERVLOC.SAK_PROV  NOT IN (SELECT A.SAK_PROV FROM T_MC_FTE A INNER JOIN T_PMP_SVC_LOC B ON A.SAK_PROV = B.SAK_PROV)
AND PROVSERVLOC.SAK_PROV_LOC   not in (select a.sak_prov_loc from t_mc_fte a inner join t_pmp_svc_loc b on a.sak_prov_loc = b.sak_prov_loc)   
and provservloc.sak_pub_hlth       = 23
AND elig.sak_prov_pgm              = 57
AND ELIG.CDE_ENROLL_STATUS        IN ( 'A' ,'G', 'X' )
--AND mcfte.cde_status1          != 'H'
AND mcd.cde_prov_id_type        = 'MCD'
AND NPI.CDE_PROV_ID_TYPE        = 'NPI'
AND npi.id_provider                = '123456789';
```

The result list i get 5 rows. It looks like this:
[Query_Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge7jp.png)

I know that the problem primarily is with two tables:
1. T_MC_FTE

```
SAK_PROV_LOC   SAK_PROV DTE_EFFECTIVE    DTE_END
------------ ---------- ------------- ----------
       32254      32254      20150401   20160331
       32254      32254      20171001   22991231
```

2. T_PMP_SVC_LOC

   ```
   SAK_PROV_LOC   SAK_PROV DTE_EFFECTIVE    DTE_END
   ------------ ---------- ------------- ----------
          30859      30859      20050101   20090630
          32254      32254      20050401   20110630
          32254      32254      20150401   20160331
          32254      32254      20171001   22991231
   ```

   the value that i do not need is the one in the T_MC_FTE table with DTE_END = 20160331.
   So, basically i am looking to get all the results from T_PMP_SVC_LOC, and the ones that match T_MC_FTE only if T_MC_FTE.DTE_END > today.
   In the end, the result should be all 4 rows from T_PMP_SVC_LOC with appropriate column values for the one record that is matched in T_MC_FTE with DTE_END > today;

Any suggestion on how to improve the UNION?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to do

```
select distinct npi_provider, 
                num_contract_max, 
                mcd_provider ...
from (
  your select statement 
)
```

However this might drop efficiency of query. Try to redesign query to not use `union` and `distinct` at all.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Paweł . However, a singel query is not the solution due to the lack of uniqueness on some of the tables. So, mapping one to many will create a whole load of "duplicate" values.

Comment: Duplicate is the root of all evil.